# Why does modifying copy of array affect original?

Tags: python, list

Hi everyone I am sorry if this is a noob question but I am using python and I have an issue where I copy an array but then when I modify the copy it affects the original. I want to add a linear offset from the boundaries matrix to a set of coordinates:

```
boundaries = [[5.818, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 5.818, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 5.818]]

xyzCoord = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [2.909, 2.909, 0.0], ...

extraX=[]
for i in range(0,len(xyzCoord)):
    toAdd=[]
    toAdd=xyzCoord[i]
    toAdd[0]=toAdd[0]+boundaries[0][0]

print xyzCoord
```

The output I expect is that xyzCoord should not be affected because I make a duplicate (toAdd) and then modify that. Strangely enough this loop does affect my xyzCoord:

The output is:

```
[[5.818, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 5.818, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 5.818]]

[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [2.909, 2.909, 0.0], ...

[[5.818, 0.0, 0.0], [8.727, 2.909, 0.0], ...
```

---

EDIT: For context, the idea is that I want to eventually make a separate list with the transposed values and then ultimately create an intercalated list but this part is holding me up. I.e. I would ideally like to create:
   [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [5.818, 0.0, 0.0], [2.909, 0.0, 0.0], [8.727, 2.909, 0.0]...]
and then make a larger loop for Y and Z. This way I could propagate some coordinates in the X Y and Z and arbitrary number of times.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is one of the most surprising things about Python - the `=` operator never makes a copy of anything! It simply attaches a new name to an existing object.

If you want to make a copy of a list, you can use a slice of the list; the slicing operator *does* make a copy.

```
toAdd=xyzCoord[i][:]
```

You can also use `copy` or `deepcopy` from the [`copy` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) to make a copy of an object.

Answer (score 1):

`toAdd` is not a duplicate. The following makes `toAdd` refer to the same sub-list as `xyzCoord[i]`:

```
toAdd = xyzCoord[i]
```

When you change elements of `toAdd`, the corresponding elements of `xyzCoord[i]` also change.

Instead of the above, write:

```
toAdd = xyzCoord[i][:]
```

This will make a (shallow) copy.

Comment: There's also `copy.deepcopy()`.

Comment: Some prefer the explicit `list(xyzCoord[i])` which reads more like "construct me a *new* list please" instead of the implicit copy made by slicing from start to finish.  The former is slower (although that is rarely a concern).

Answer (score 0):

Because your using an array of arrays (list of lists) the inner list is an object so you are only copying the reference of the inner object instead of copying the values.