# Python 3 - Am I correctly using indexing?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, indexing

I am writing a little program that takes 4 numbers `(173,210,94,164)` and does the following:

1. The first number in a new set will be the absolute value of the difference between the first and second numbers. (ex. `abs(173-210)`  ->  `37`)
2. The second number in the set is the absolute value of the difference between the second and third numbers (ex. `abs(210-94)`  ->  `116`), and so on, looping around with the 1st and 4th numbers at the end.

For these numbers, the second set should look like `(37, 116, 70, 9)` but when I run my code, I get `(37, 116, 70, 127)`. What's making the last number `127` instead of `9`?

```
numbers = [173, 210, 94, 164]
counter = 0
while numbers != [0, 0, 0, 0]:
    oldnums = numbers
    numbers[0] = abs(oldnums[0] - oldnums[1])
    numbers[1] = abs(oldnums[1] - oldnums[2])
    numbers[2] = abs(oldnums[2] - oldnums[3])
    numbers[3] = abs(oldnums[3] - oldnums[0])
    print(numbers)
    counter += 1
print('Number of iterations to (0,0,0,0): ' + str(counter))
```

Comment: ``oldnums = numbers`` gives two names to a single list - as you assign to numbers, you're changing oldnums as well.  Use ``oldness = numbers[:]`` or ``oldness = list(numbers)`` to make a copy that won't be modified as you modify the other list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python modifying copy of array affects original?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746434/python-modifying-copy-of-array-affects-original)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you use the already updated values again. The `oldnumbers = numbers` doesn't do a copy so when you calculate the last value: `numbers[3] = abs(oldnums[3] - oldnums[0])` you use the new `numbers[0]` (which is identical to `oldnums[0]`) value - which is not what you wanted.

However you don't need to copy the list at all. Python can do unpacking:

```
numbers = [173, 210, 94, 164]
counter = 0
while numbers != [0, 0, 0, 0]:
    numbers[:] = (abs(numbers[0] - numbers[1]), 
                  abs(numbers[1] - numbers[2]), 
                  abs(numbers[2] - numbers[3]), 
                  abs(numbers[3] - numbers[0]))
    print(numbers)
    counter += 1
print('Number of iterations to (0,0,0,0): ' + str(counter))
```

Comment: What is `numbers[:]` the last item?

Comment: The `:` means that all items are accessed. In this case it means all items are overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

`numbers` is a pointer which is pointing to the location in memory where your `[173, 210, 94, 164]` is stored.
When you do `oldnums = numbers`, you are making `oldnums` point to the same memory location.
Thus any change you do to the data where numbers is pointing is also reflected in `oldnums`. For your purpose, you can use

> oldnums = list(numbers)